# How to use a class member variable in a unary predicate?

Tags: c++, class, predicate

Suppose I have the following code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>

bool pred(float const &val)
{
    //return fabs(val) < epsilon;
}

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(float eps) : epsilon(eps) { }

    int Bar(std::vector<float> vec)
    {
        return std::count_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), pred);
    }
private:
    float epsilon;
}
```

I want to have the unary predicate `pred()` as a class method so that it can access the `epsilon` member variable. I've seen examples using the `operator()`, but if I got it right, the operator is supposed to compare the entire class instance. I only need to compare the given `std::vector`'s elements in `Bar()`. Is it possible to create an unary predicate as a class member? If not, is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a C++98 solution:

```
class Pred{
    private:
        float eps;
    public:
        Pred(float eps) : eps(eps){
        }

        bool operator()(const float& val){
            return val < eps;
        }
};
```

And use it like this:

```
int Bar(std::vector<float> vec)
{
    Pred pred(epsilon);
    return std::count_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), pred);
}
```

Note that this solution is general for whenever you need a predicate that requires additional data; write a class containing the additional data as class members, and overload the `()` operator. You can initialize an object of the class with the appropriate data and then use it as the predicate.

Comment: Very nice, thank you! Even though the C++11 seems more elegant, I was searching for a C++98 solution, thus I will accept this answer.

Answer (score 4):

if you are using c++ 11 which you should be the easy way is a lambda

```
int Bar(std::vector<float> vec)
{
    return std::count_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(),[this](const float &f)
    {
        return fabs(val) < epsilon;
    });
}
```

Comment: I did not use it for now, but I will ask if the coding guidelines allow use of c++11. It would be nice to see a C++98 solution though.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that pred() needs two parameters but std::count_if wants a function that takes only one.  @Praetorian's c++11 solution with lambdas is optimal.  But without access to that, you should be able to use std::bind1st which does the operator () solution for you without you explicitly creating a class to do it.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <functional>

bool pred(float const &val, float epsilon)
{
    return fabs(val) < epsilon;
}

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(float eps) : epsilon(eps) { }

    int Bar(std::vector<float> vec)
    {
        return std::count_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::bind1st(std::less<float>(), epsilon));
    }
private:
    float epsilon;
};
```

Comment: Very nice indeed! Now I don't know which answer to accept. :D